# Chess Glyphs in Logitech Revue

Tags: fonts

On my Logitech Revue, different glyphs are rendered for the chess symbols than on my computer.

Computer:
[image]
Revue:
[image]

Using [Panopticlick](http://panopticlick.eff.org), I've ascertained that the fonts installed on the Revue are:

> AndroidClock
>   AndroidClock Highlight
>   AndroidClock Solid
>   Clockopia
>   Droid Sans
>   Droid Sans Arabic
>   Droid Sans Fallback
>   Droid Sans Hebrew
>   Droid Sans Mono
>   Droid Sans Thai
>   Droid Serif

However, applying these to the chess glyphs (using @font-face) on my computer gives the same glyphs as with no font selected. **What font are the glyphs I'm seeing, and why doesn't it show up to Flash (Panopticlick reports that it got the list from Flash)?**

If this is the wrong place to post this, I'm sorry, but there isn't a Typography Stack Exchange, and this does involve Android.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Whoops, fixed now.